# Movie scene where guy dressed as Darth Vader tries to use the force on a cab?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I know it was made in the last 20 years because it was when the VFX effects were ok but it's not *very* recent.

It was near a convention. Vader tried to use the Force because they were at a crossroad, walking to the convention, and the car had to abruptly stop before hitting him. The friend tells him something like

> "its not worth it".

---

I thought it was from *[Race to Witch Mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_to_Witch_Mountain)* (with The Rock as the taxi driver) but I just watched the whole movie and it isn't there.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was there any actual magic, or was it realistic?

Answer (score 14):

Could this be *[Ted 2](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2637276/)?*

As Vader threatens to use the Force, Obi Wan's line is

> "Come on. It's not worth it, man. It's not worth it".